# Flipping game logic help required

Tags: java, android

i am working on a small game and i have written logic already, game shows 4 rows and 3 columns means total 12 cells or buttons.

they appear 2 seconds and i show all the icons on it and after that i disappear them, then user has to match the icons to complete the game.

I am using gridview for this purpose and code is given below of my entire game logic, but clicking on the button is very slow any one guide me why my game is slow onclicking the cell and how can i improve it?
[image]

```
 public class GameScreenFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    int i = 0;
    private GridView gridView;
    private TextView textViewShowTime;
    public int[] tapherePictureArray = {R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here, R.drawable.tap_here};
    public int[] objectPictureArray = {R.drawable.bettry, R.drawable.htc_logo, R.drawable.uber, R.drawable.uber, R.drawable.htc_name, R.drawable.qualocommi, R.drawable.hi_res_audio, R.drawable.qualocommi, R.drawable.bettry, R.drawable.htc_name, R.drawable.htc_logo, R.drawable.hi_res_audio};
    public int[] intervalObjectArray = {R.drawable.bettry, R.drawable.htc_logo, R.drawable.uber, R.drawable.uber, R.drawable.htc_name, R.drawable.qualocommi, R.drawable.hi_res_audio, R.drawable.qualocommi, R.drawable.bettry, R.drawable.htc_name, R.drawable.htc_logo, R.drawable.hi_res_audio};
    public ArrayList<Integer> listRandomObjectPicture;
    public ArrayList<Integer> listRandomIntervalObjectPicture;
    MainActivity context;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    int isttId, secondId;
    int oddpos, evenpos;
    Chronometer stopWatch;
    long startTime;
    public ArrayList<Integer> disableposition;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_screen, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        textViewShowTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_show_time);
        stopWatch = (Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.chrono);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        disableposition = new ArrayList<>();
        context = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context, intervalObjectArray, disableposition);
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context, tapherePictureArray, disableposition);
                gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        textViewShowTime.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                        textViewShowTime.setText("00");
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                .setTitle("Time Up")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setMessage("Oops! Looks like you ran out of time. try it again")
                                .setPositiveButton("try again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                                        context.replaceFragmentWithoutBackstack(new GameScreenFragment());
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })

                                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                .show();
                    }

                };
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        }, 2000);


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        i++;
        Log.e("counter", i + "");
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            secondId = objectPictureArray[position];
            evenpos = position;
            tapherePictureArray[position] = objectPictureArray[position];
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridView.invalidateViews();
            if (isttId == secondId && evenpos != oddpos) {
                tapherePictureArray[oddpos] = objectPictureArray[oddpos];
                tapherePictureArray[evenpos] = objectPictureArray[evenpos];
                disableposition.add(oddpos);
                disableposition.add(evenpos);
                Log.e("Size", disableposition.size() + "");
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                gridView.invalidateViews();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (disableposition.size() == 12) {
                            countDownTimer.cancel();
                            context.winTime = textViewShowTime.getText().toString();
                            int temptime = Integer.parseInt(context.winTime);
                            int actualTime = 45 - temptime;
                            context.winTime = String.valueOf(actualTime);

                            context.fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                            context.replaceFragment(new TimerShowFragment());
                        }
                    }
                }, 500);

            } else {
                i = 0;
                tapherePictureArray[position] = objectPictureArray[position];
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                gridView.invalidateViews();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tapherePictureArray[evenpos] = R.drawable.tap_here;
                        tapherePictureArray[oddpos] = R.drawable.tap_here;
                        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        gridView.invalidateViews();

                    }
                }, 300);
            }
        } else {
            oddpos = position;
            isttId = objectPictureArray[position];
            tapherePictureArray[position] = objectPictureArray[position];
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridView.invalidateViews();

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slow as in the code takes awhile to execute or because you're waiting 500ms for your Handler code to execute? First, your log call should be to debug not error. Next create a global Handler and initialize it beforehand. Then limit calls to notifyDataSetChanged() and invalidateViews() as those will cause redraws which will run on the UI thread.

Comment: Also, if you're running on the emulator it could react much slower than a real device.